# How to move iOS apps from one developer account to another?

Tags: ios, iphone-developer-program

I have 2 different apple developer account both are company developer account. I want to switch some apps to first account to another. 
Is this possible? If yes then how I can do this. Please guide me.

Comment: As I can remember, you are able to transfer one app to another developer account through iTunes Connect. There is an option on the right-hand side once you've clicked on the app you want to transfer.

Note: Once the switch has been complete, you will no longer be able to access it from first account.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Apple developer account processes.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Yes it's possible. Go to **iTunesConnect**, click on the app you want to transfer and click on "transfer app".

The app will still be available on the app store during the transfer.

More information is available [here in Apple Documentation.](https://help.apple.com/itunes-connect/developer/#/deved688524f)

Comment: Here are the direct link to the transfer procedure :
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html

Comment: Does Pushnotification Work after transferring the app ?

Comment: @Abishek Mitra Check this out. It states that the certificates have to be renewed on the receivers account. So i assume that it doesn't work anymore. https://help.apple.com/itunes-connect/developer/#/deved688524f

Comment: number of downloads are also transferred or not ?

Comment: if my first account is enterprise account then.

Comment: Developer account is closed now. Can I transfer old apps ?

Answer (score 16):

You will find all the info you need here: [Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/10_ManagingYourApplications/ManagingYourApplications.html)

That is the official documentation, here's the relevant section:

> As the volume of app acquisitions and purchases increases between
>   developers, an automated process for transferring apps between
>   developers has been created. Through this process, you can transfer
>   the ownership of an app to another developer without removing the app
>   from the App Store while retaining the reviews and chart position.
>   There is no limit to the number of apps you can transfer, but you must
>   transfer each app individually. Preparing to Transfer an App
>
> After you have agreed to terms with another developer or company
>   outside of iTunes Connect, you can begin the process of transferring
>   your app. Only the team agent can initiate or complete an app
>   transfer.
>
> Before you transfer an app to another developer, you need to ensure
>   that the app meets all of the following criteria:
>
> App can not be using an iCloud entitlement.
>
> App can not be using a Passbook entitlement.
>
> All iAd related account information that is pending setup or pending
>   an update must be completed before the app can be transferred.
>
> There is at least one approved version of the app.
>
> App must be in a transferable state. You can transfer your app when it
>   is one of the following states.
>
> - Ready for Sale
> - Pending Contract
> - Prepare for Upload
> - Developer Removed from Sale
> - Invalid Binary
> - Developer Rejected
> - Rejected
>
> Your developer account is not currently in the migration process (from
>   an individual to a company).
>
> Transferor is on the latest version of the master agreements for the
>   same contract content types, including iOS paid, iOS free, iAd, Mac OS
>   X free, and Mac OS X paid.
>
> App does not have any approved auto-renewable subscription, free
>   subscription, or non-renewing subscription In-App Purchases.
>
> Note: Even if you have had subscriptions that were approved in the
>   past, but were deleted, the app is not currently eligible for App
>   Transfer.
>
> In-app purchase Product IDs on the app are not the same Product IDs on
>   any apps in the recipient’s account.
>
> In-app purchases must be in one of the following states:
>
> - Approved
> - Ready to Submit
> - Developer Removed from Sale
> - Rejected
>
> Only apps that meet the above requirements can be transferred to
>   another developer.
>
> After ensuring that your app meets all of the transfer requirements,
>   you can begin the transfer process. Transferring an App
>
> Only the team agent with the Apple ID and team ID can transfer an app.
>   The team agent initiates an app transfer by clicking the Transfer App
>   button. Only the team agent is able to see this button.

Comment: Can I change the bundle ID after transfer?

Comment: @TarekEl-Mallah did you find the answer on change the bundle ID ? and one more question, can we perform an update on the same bundle ID. (NOTE: the bundle ID has been transferred to the new apple developer account but the team identifier cannot be same!!)

Comment: I didn't find a way to change the bundle ID. In short, to change bundle ID you need to create new application. ( this is as far as I know )

Comment: is it possible to transfer app within same account? like merge 2 apps? and the existing users of both app will get only one update as in result?

Comment: @TarekEl-Mallah it's not possible to update the Bundle ID after a build has been uploaded for the app. [read here](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/deved688524f)