# How do you transfer a iOS app that is in development to another developer acount

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

I have been working on an app under my own personal account and have been using TestFlight.  I now want to transfer this to a company developer account and remove it from my personal. For the life of me I can not find the steps unless the app is already published. This app has not yet been published and there is no "Transfer" option on the app page.

Comment: [Does this help?](https://support.appmachine.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000012284-Transfer-your-app-to-another-iOS-Developer-Account)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to move iOS apps from one developer account to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19154626/how-to-move-ios-apps-from-one-developer-account-to-another)

Comment: no sorry that does not help as there is no "Transfer link"

Comment: @NSNoob do you know of a resource that shows how to do this if the app has not been released yet?